# How to write a properly joined query with method based syntax in Entity SQL?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, dbcontext

I am working on a larger system with Entity Framework. Personally, I do like the method based syntax for writing LINQ / ESQL queries.

But I cannnot figure out, how the following joined query can be written properly.

Suppose, i have the following Entity classes and DbContext repository:

```
public class A
{
    [Key]
    public int ID{get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<B> BCollection { get; set; }
}
public class B
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual A A { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<C> CCollection { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<D> DCollection { get; set; }
}
public class C
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual B B { get; set; }
}
public class D
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual B B { get; set; }
}
public class Entities : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<A> SetA { get; set; }
    public DbSet<B> SetB { get; set; }
    public DbSet<C> SetC { get; set; }
    public DbSet<D> SetD { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to get the "whole" tree: All items of class A, with their attached items of class B, where each item of class B is equipped with items of class C and D.

I can do that with this query:

```
var x = db.SetA
            .Include(a => a.BCollection.Select(b => b.CCollection))
            .Include(a => a.BCollection.Select(b => b.DCollection))
            .ToList();
```

But i think this can be done easier, right?

Please note: I DO want to eager load the whole tree, as I DO NOT want to use lazy loading.

**Edit:**

This is not a question regarding one single problem, my question is more about the approach. When I write my queries like shown above, EF generates one hell of a giant query:

```
 SELECT [Project3].[ID] AS [ID],
   [Project3].[C9] AS [C1],
   [Project3].[C2] AS [C2],
   [Project3].[C3] AS [C3],
   [Project3].[C4] AS [C4],
   [Project3].[C1] AS [C5],
   [Project3].[C5] AS [C6],
   [Project3].[C6] AS [C7],
   [Project3].[C7] AS [C8],
   [Project3].[C8] AS [C9]
FROM   (SELECT [Extent1].[ID]     AS [ID],
           [UnionAll1].[C1]   AS [C1],
           [UnionAll1].[ID]   AS [C2],
           [UnionAll1].[ID1]  AS [C3],
           [UnionAll1].[A_ID] AS [C4],
           [UnionAll1].[ID2]  AS [C5],
           [UnionAll1].[B_ID] AS [C6],
           [UnionAll1].[C2]   AS [C7],
           [UnionAll1].[C3]   AS [C8],
           CASE
             WHEN ([UnionAll1].[ID] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int)
             ELSE 1
           END                AS [C9]
    FROM   [dbo].[A] AS [Extent1]
           OUTER APPLY (SELECT CASE
                                 WHEN ([Extent3].[ID] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int)
                                 ELSE 1
                               END               AS [C1],
                               [Extent2].[ID]    AS [ID],
                               [Extent2].[ID]    AS [ID1],
                               [Extent2].[A_ID]  AS [A_ID],
                               [Extent3].[ID]    AS [ID2],
                               [Extent3].[B_ID]  AS [B_ID],
                               CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C2],
                               CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C3]
                        FROM   [dbo].[B] AS [Extent2]
                               LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[C] AS [Extent3]
                                 ON [Extent2].[ID] = [Extent3].[B_ID]
                        WHERE  [Extent1].[ID] = [Extent2].[A_ID]
                        UNION ALL


                        SELECT 2                 AS [C1],
                               [Extent4].[ID]    AS [ID],
                               [Extent4].[ID]    AS [ID1],
                               [Extent4].[A_ID]  AS [A_ID],
                               CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C2],
                               CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C3],
                               [Extent5].[ID]    AS [ID2],
                               [Extent5].[B_ID]  AS [B_ID]
                        FROM   [dbo].[B] AS [Extent4]
                               INNER JOIN [dbo].[D] AS [Extent5]
                                 ON [Extent4].[ID] = [Extent5].[B_ID]
                        WHERE  [Extent1].[ID] = [Extent4].[A_ID]) AS [UnionAll1]) AS [Project3]
ORDER  BY [Project3].[ID] ASC,
      [Project3].[C9] ASC,
      [Project3].[C3] ASC,
      [Project3].[C1] ASC
```

But what I actually would write myself is something like:

```
SELECT     *
FROM         D RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                  B ON D.B_ID = B.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  C ON B.ID = C.B_ID RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                  A ON B.A_ID = A.ID
```

I hope this helps to clarify my question. The point is: How can I make Entity Framework generate more efficient queries?

Comment: Well if you wanna "eager load" your tree, without changing the LazyLoading configuration, your solution is fine (but it's gonna be one "heavy" sql request...)

Comment: Sure, i do not want to use Lazy Loading. Better one heavy request than 10.000 lightweight requests. But youre right, the result is one heavy query containing three subqueries and a lot of UNION. So how could i improve on that?

Comment: You can try to use an anonymous object (`db.SetA.Select(seta => new {a = seta, bcoll = seta.BCollection` etc.), and test if it's faster. If perf is the FINAL problem... use a "hard written" sql request.

Comment: Not sure how to go into the third level of depth with anonymous types. Also if i understand this right, this query will give me a projection instead of an object tree. So i would have to convert the whole thing. I updated the question to show where i am pointing at... If i start writing SQL manually for every joined query, where's the point in using an ORM?

Comment: Well, that's the point : if your performance are fine, don't look at SQL generated by your ORM. Look at them when performance becomes a problem. An ORM is not suited for everything. We use EF too, but had to generate "BULK INSERT SQL" for some specific tasks which were too slow with EF.

Comment: I understand you. But it is hard to accept this as an answer. When using an ORM in a prototype, I want to know which SQL is generated and how it performs. Everyone can see, that the generated union query will take longer than the manually written joined query. And i think that in this case, it is because i wrote the wrong ESQL query.

Comment: Well, I understand, of course. You could also write your own joins (search for 'right outer join linq' 'left outer join linq'). It might be better. http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2009/06/10/c-left-outer-joins-with-linq/ for example

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12421/discussion-between-ckonig-and-raphael-althaus)

Answer (score 1):

I think following LINQ would generate a "mega" query you are looking for:

```
    var query =
        db.SetA
            .Join(db.SetB, a => a, b => b.A, (a, b) => new
                                                           {
                                                               A = a,
                                                               B = b
                                                           })
            .Join(db.SetC, ab => ab.B, c => c.B, (ab, c) => new
                                                                {
                                                                    A = ab.A,
                                                                    B = ab.B,
                                                                    C = c
                                                                })
            .Join(db.SetD, abc => abc.B, d => d.B, (abc, d) => new
                                                                   {
                                                                       A = abc.A,
                                                                       B = abc.B,
                                                                       C = abc.C,
                                                                       D = d
                                                                   });

    foreach (var abcd in query)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}-{1}-{2}-{3}", abcd.A.ID, abcd.B.ID, abcd.C.ID, abcd.D.ID);
    }
```

Comment: Interesting... but still, this gives me a projection which i would need to map into a tree of entities.

Comment: Ok. And what is your expectation? Somthing like `Tuple<A,B,C,D>` ?

Comment: Just what i would get from `var x = db.SetA
            .Include(a => a.BCollection.Select(b => b.CCollection))
            .Include(a => a.BCollection.Select(b => b.DCollection))
            .ToList();` : Objects, with their navigation properties set, so i can work object oriented right away without mapping